# java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.springframework.kafka.listener.RecordInterceptor

Tags: spring-boot, maven, apache-kafka, spring-kafka, spring-boot-starter-parent

I have my spring boot kafka application with maven and I have updated the older versions with the latestone for spring-boot-starter-parent and spring-kafka as below.

1. spring-boot-starter-parent
   from  2.1.7.RELEASE --to--> 2.2.7.RELEASE
2. spring-kafka
   from  2.3.7.RELEASE --to--> 2.4.6.RELEASE

With the older versions, the application was running fine but with the updated one, I am getting issue.

java.lang.IllegalStateException: Failed to load ApplicationContext
.
.
.
.
.
.

Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.springframework.kafka.listener.RecordInterceptor

Please guide with the most compatible kafka version with spring 2.2.x.

Comment: Edit the question to show your complete POM; that error indicates you are NOT using the versions you claim. RecordInterceptor was added in spring-kafka 2.2.7.